# How to select the singlerow and Insert and delete the rows

Tags: android, realm

I am new to RealM library and here is my requirement I need to insert 10000 rows by default which I have inserted successfully. But I have having couple of issues with Selecting, Inserting and Deleting the rows.

Below is the code adding the Rows to DB

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
        realm.beginTransaction();

        TestModel model = new TestModel();
        model.setId(i);
        model.setName("Test App");
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(model);
        realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

Could some please guide me here!

1. Select a row - I want to select the 30th row? How it's is possible. I have tired with below code, but couldn't achieve it.
2. Inserting new rows - Additionally, I want to insert the new rows
3. Deleting news rows - I want to delete the news rows which has been added in step 2

   private void deleteRecords() {

   ```
   TestModel model = new TestModel();
   RealmResults<TestModel> results
                   = realm.where(TestModel.class)
                   .equalTo("name", model.getName())
                   .findAllAsync();

           realm.beginTransaction();
           if (results != null) {
               results.clear();
           }

           realm.commitTransaction();
       }
   ```

Comment: add your code snippet for better view

Comment: @SultanMahmud, I have already added!

Comment: If the idea of "index within the database" is important, then you should also save that it's the 0th, 1st, 2nd, ... as a field. Deletions can change the order of items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For inserting a row in realm do like this

   ```
   Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
   Person person = new Person();
   person.setName("ABC");
   realm.executeTransaction(r -> {
       // Add a object.
       realm.insertOrUpdate(person);
   });
   ```
2. Deleting single or multiple row from realm

   ```
   Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction(realm -> {
       RealmResults<Person> result = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("name","ABC").findAll();
       result.deleteAllFromRealm();
   });
   ```
3. Query a row from realm -

   ```
   Person person=Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Person.class).equalTo("name","ABC").findFirst();
   ```

Comment: Thanks , If I want to delete the row from 10000 t0 11000 I need to beginsWith() method?

Comment: Good way to delete the results is to first query the result on the basis of primary key, 
and in your case you can use between operator like - .between("id",10000,11000)